# NAM GUI does not display

Tags: ns2

I just started using Ubuntu and I need to run NS2 with the NAM gui.

I successfully installed ns2 and nam and I am able to run ns2 scripts.

However when I try to open NAM from the Terminal, it simply does not work.

When I run nam from the terminal, I get the message :

nam:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsGtr.png)

The terminal prompt then immediately comes back.

I am using Ubuntu in a GUI environment.

Output of echo "$DISPLAY" :

`mehdihaddoud@mehdihaddoud-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/TP$ echo "$DISPLAY" :0 mehdihaddoud@mehdihaddoud-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/TP$`

Comment: Are running in a GUI environment, or a text terminal? Please [edit] your question and show us `echo "$DISPLAY"`.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: Please also add Ubuntu version to the question : The Ubuntu 'nam' package was corrupt from Ubuntu 13.xx to 19.04 . ........ Valid nam packages https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNLXVVSnNFSXpWUGs?resourcekey=0-l7ZPIxkG17JwSO5CDA4ONA&usp=sharing ............... P.S.: Nam may not work in Cygwin. NS-2 / nam may not work in VirtualBox, wmWare.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 21.04 in VirtualBox

Comment: ns2 INFO https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing  ...... Important note : 
Conditions for ns2 → A 'Linux OS' installed to a hard disk partition. 
Both VirtualBox and wmWare have resulted in poor unusable 'ns' executable since 2017.

Comment: About 'nam' : Why not install the Ubuntu `nam`  package  https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/nam → enable the **universe** repo.

Answer (score 0):

nam Network Animator for network simulation can be installed by the following command in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install nam
```

To launch Nam Console GUI from the terminal type `nam`

[image]

[image]